# How to avoid using service location when using dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, anti-patterns, vb.net, service-locator

I am trying to use dependency injection in a WPF application, and I really can't figure how to avoid using service location, which is considered to be an anti-pattern in many articles. I am using the MVVM Light framework.

```vb
Interface I
  Property N As Integer
End Interface
Class A
  Private _i As I
  Sub New(i As I)
    _i = i
  End Sub
  Sub DoWork()
    _i.N = 1
  End Sub
End Class
Class B
  Implements I
  Property N As Integer Implements I.N
End Class
Class C
  Sub DoSomething()
    REM IS THIS ANTI-PATTERN???
    Dim instanceA = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance(Of A)()
    instanceA.DoWork()
  End Sub
End Class
Module M
  Sub Main()
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register(Of A)()
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register(Of I, B)()
    Dim c As New C
    c.DoSomething()
  End Sub
End Module
```

When I need to use an instance of `A` in class `C`, is it an anti-pattern to use IoC container as service locator? Is there any other way to autoconstruct an instance of `A` with the required dependencies?

Comment: I'd say it is an antipattern - it's a *hidden* dependency on a global variable, so you're not really injecting a dependency - you're resolving it internally. You should pass the type as a dependency in the class constructor and let the container wire it up for you from all registrations in the application root.

Comment: But HOW I can resolve that one concrete class with dependencies that I need without calling GetInstance? As far as I know, you have to call GetInstance somewhere, to let IoC container to inject dependencies.

Comment: No, you don't have to call it explicitly call it inside a class. Container will 'auto-wire' the dependency for you. So, if `C` depends on `A`, the container will create `A` and inject it in `C` during the creation of `C` (which also comes from the container). If you want to resolve something from inside `Main` (the root of the application) then yes, you have to use the container, but 'inside' any other class in the application that's set up by the container - nope.

Comment: There must be some central point where you create instances using IoC container for auto-wiring and passing them further and its not Main, because it is WPF application with lot of independent classes. I am starting to hate this fucking pattern more and more, because only thing you are thinking of are dependencies and how to pass them instead of business logic and it does not bring you anything good that is worth of doing all this bullshit.

Comment: Do you need to call GetInstance only once or multiple times? If multiple times, what is difference between each call?

Comment: I am calling GetInstance where it is needed (usually 1 times in constructor) to avoid having constructor bloated with parameters and to avoid breaking encapsulation by exposing unnecessary properties.

Comment: How many parameters is "bloated"? And how is exposing dependency in constructor "breaking encapsulation"?

Comment: Bloated = more than one and if I will need some new functionality, there will be probably need of more because of that DI. To avoid bloating constructor you can do property injection instead of constructor injection and that is breaking encapsulation, because you are exposing internals to outside of class and anyone can assign Nothing to these properties which will lead to runtime exception.

Comment: You've hit the obvious snag where every change means piling more dependencies onto a constructor. We've all been there. Keep at it. Evolve to designs that have small classes with few arguments in the constructor. Keep your classes open for extension and closed for modification. Look into SOLID.

Comment: I think I am doing something very badly, or using things for purposes that they were not designed for. The problem is that I am single person working on medium size project and I am analyst, architect, developer, designer and tester all by myself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using 'Dim c As New C', instead of registering C in the IoC container and requesting it from there. The dependency C requests in DoSomething should be passed in the constructor, which IoC wires for you. What makes it a bit hard is the fact that your IoC container seems to be a Singleton and is therefore accessible from everywhere. You should try and avoid this.

Service location is indeed an antipattern, but you need to use service location at least ONCE for your application to work, as you rightly put in your question. This is done by creating a main application class that is manually retrieved from the IoC container. The rest of your application goes from there. If you do things right, you get a single main class from the IoC container and the rest is wired in by the container itself. It only turns into an antipattern when you start interspersing this IoC code into other application code.

Thinking about the dependencies actually helps your code. It's a lot easier to see where you are going wrong with the design of a class if you are adding the seventh dependency to the constructor, instead of New'ing up the seventh class in a method. Once you get your head around to thinking in terms of IoC you start to write small, focused and well-testable classes, but you have to sink your teeth into it for a bit until you really start to see the advantages.

Comment: Your suggested solution will lead to one big god object which is holding instances of everything that can be used somewhere plus registering everything in IoC container and I am not doing this. And if you add some new stuff, you must add it to that god object too.

Comment: Not really as some things can (and should) be resolved dynamically. For example, you can have a CommandHandler class that takes a command, from the type of command gets a <CertainTypeOfCommand>Executor via IoC and hands the command of to that. CommandHandler would take an IList of ICommandExecutors in the constructor, NOT have a constructor that takes every single Executor hardcoded.  Adding more Executor-classes does not mean you add to the constructor.

Comment: My main problem is where to start resolving dependencies. I have main window and this window have view model. Everything is directed by this main window's view model so this view model must call GetInstance every time instance of something is needed to pass somewhere. There is no better solution than this except creating some monstrosity that is even more complex than application itself. Besides, I am not doing unit tests since faking real functionality is not test at all.

Comment: @Ondřej "one big god object which is holding instances of everything that can be used somewhere" Isn't that the very definition of IoC container?

Comment: It is certainly NOT. Main purpose of IoC container is stuffing constructors of registered classes with instances of appropriate classes. How instances are created and stored depends on how they are registered.

Comment: IoC is about managing big chains of dependent objects and there is very little benefit in DI just for the sake of it. DI and TDD work well together because they tend to evolve an architecture towards small, single-responsible and generally SOLID objects. What do YOU expect to gain from using DI in the first place?

Comment: By using ninja design patterns I am expecting to avoid getting mentally ill when project will grow bigger and more complex.

Answer (score 0):

First off, yes. Using an IoC that way is an anti-pattern. You've got a global variable in disguise there.

It is natural for dependencies to "bubble up" toward the entry point of the program and constructors grow in size. That's just the nature of the beast. However let's step back and ask ourselves a question.

> *Why do we want DI to begin with?*

We want DI so we can easily fake dependencies for easier testing. *They're for testing.* **These huge constructors never need to be called in production code.**

You can use an IoC for this, but you don't have to. Ditch it if you want.

I might get creamed for this, but here goes nothing...

I picked this trick up from [Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052), but let me be clear that I am kind of abusing the technique in order to shrink the size of the constructors that actually get called in production code.

Most often, the dependencies way up our chain don't change at runtime. They're effectively constant, but we still want the ability to fake those dependencies. Consider the following example. (Excuse my C# please)

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(Foo foo, Bar bar, Qux qux)
    {
        //...
    }
 }
```

But in reality, our production code always uses the same values for all of our parameters. That's fine. Overload the ctor and create the new instances inside of it. (It's DI blasphemy, I know. Whatever. I don't care. It works.)

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(Foo foo, Bar bar, Qux qux)
    {
        //....
    }

    public Class1()
        :this(new Foo(), new Bar(), new Qux())
    {
        //...
    }
 }
```

Now your production code calls the parameterless constructor and your tests call the *real* constructor. Problem solved. No fancy framework needed. Of course, there *should be* a way to accomplish the same thing with your IoC framework, but without knowing the details of what you're using, I can't say how. Unfortunately, VB.Net doesn't get the same love when it comes to frameworks as C#. Regardless, I thought you should see the "quick and dirty" way to do this. You can always switch to an IoC container later when your projects is of sufficient complexity to warrant it.

Comment: _Unfortunately, VB.Net doesn't get the same love when it comes to frameworks as C#._  

What you mean by this? You can use any IL binary code in any .NET language...

Comment: @Ondřej Vb.Net has poor lambda support and many frameworks I've seen use them heavily. It was just a passing thought.

Comment: Must be because we still target 3.5 @Ondřej http://stackoverflow.com/q/2099676/3198973 No need to be a dick by the way. That's no way to treat someone who was trying to help you out.